# Is there a tool that directly exports a .DWG map with coordinates to GEOTIFF?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, dwg

**Input:** AutoCAD
**Output:** GeoTIFF

Is there a tool that directly exports a .DWG map with coordinates to GEOTIFF?

Comment: Is the DWG in real-world coordinates? If so QGIS can export to geotiff.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, Can you describe the process?

Comment: Convert Map To Raster geoprocessing tool. Will convert the map extent to a raster file.

Comment: We have many *.DWG files and want to export to *.geotiff to open on webmap application. Im looking for a suitable software to include in my current data process. The data type I want to use to export is *dwg (to *geotiff). 
Could you help to advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A view years ago I was faced with the same problem and was looking for an appropriate software to bulk convert a large number of *.DWG files to GEOTIFF. Unfortunately, none of the advertised products could meet my requirements. So I decided to build my own solution with the help of the commercial **OpenDesign Teigha** library. Although I cannot share the code of the bulk conversion program, I would like to give a few tips to do the conversion by hand.

Converting AutoCAD DWGs to GeoTIFF is a complicated task because of the specific design of CAD drawings and the missing possibility to directly print to GeoPDF. Without wanting to start another riots between AutoCAD and Microstation users, Microstation has a clear advantage here.

We can print to PDF in AutoCAD as well, but we have to georeference the PDF output manually. To ease the printing process in AutoCAD, all our drawings were provided with multiple layouts and paperspace viewports. Therefore, we split the conversion task in certain steps:

1. printing viewport to PDF
2. georeferencing the PDF
3. translating the PDF to TIF

If you are working with AutoCAD you can try my adapted AutoLISP routine below (*vp2tif.lsp*) to simplify  the georeferencing using **GDAL** (i.e. **OSGeo4W** *gdal_translate*). There‘s no way to use AutoCAD-LT or DWGTrueview to solve the task.

After loading this routine in AutoCAD you need to perform the following steps:

1. Call the new AutoCAD command *VP2TIF* and select the paperspace viewport you want to export.
   The routine will return the **size** of the viewport and the **command syntax** to georeference and convert with *gdal_translate*.

```
Command: VP2TIF

Select objects: 1 found

Select objects:

Command: Size: 750 x 202
gdal_translate --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 600 --config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 4 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES -outsize 7500 0 -a_srs EPSG:9272 -gcp 0 0 9950.68 5325522.16 -gcp 7500 0 10151.29 5324799.49 -gcp 0 2020 9756.04 5325468.13 -mo CUTLINE="POLYGON((9756.04 5325468.13,9956.65 5324745.46,10151.29 5324799.49,9950.68 5325522.16,9756.04 5325468.13))" <file.pdf> <file.tif>
```

2. Select one of the AutoCAD PDF printer drivers and create a custom page size using the size info returned by VP2TIF (i.e 750 x 202). Set all page borders to "0". Align the page exactly to your paperspace viewport.
3. Print to a PDF file
4. Copy the gdal_translate command line into *OSGeo4W Shell* and replace the file place holders with your file names (i.e. myfile.pdf myfile.tif). It's always wise to store the WKT syntax of the bounding box in your GEOTIFF (i.e. -mo CUTLINE=POLYGON...), so that you can read this data afterwards and collect all polygons to build an overview of your drawing frames.

That's it, the GeoTiff is ready to be loaded into QGIS or somewhere else.

```lisp
;;; vp2tif.lsp
;;;
;;; Returns GDAL command to translate a paperspace viewport PDF printout to TIF
;;; 
;;; Supports clipped viewports.
;;; If vp-outline is called when in mspace it detects
;;; the active viewport.
;;;
;;; c:vp2tif
;;;
;;; original code from By Jimmy Bergmark (vp-outline.lsp: https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/topic/1173-modelspace-coordinates-from-paperspace-viewports)
;;; Copyright (C) 1997-2006 JTB World, All Rights Reserved
;;; Website: [url="http://www.jtbworld.com"]www.jtbworld.com[/url]
;;; E-mail: [email="info@jtbworld.com"]info@jtbworld.com[/email]
;;;
;;; 2000-04-10
;;; 2003-11-19 Added support for drawing the outline in other ucs/view than world/current
;;;
;;; 2006-04-06 Added support for twisted views Tom Beauford
;;;
;;; Tested on AutoCAD 2000, 2000i, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2007
(vl-load-com)
(defun dxf (n ent) (cdr (assoc n ent)))
(defun ax:List->VariantArray (lst)
 (vlax-Make-Variant
   (vlax-SafeArray-Fill
     (vlax-Make-SafeArray
       vlax-vbDouble
       (cons 0 (- (length lst) 1))
     )
     lst
   )
 )
)
(defun c:VP2TIF (/ ad ss en ent pl plist xy n vpbl vpur msbl msur ven vpno ok ps_list)
 (setq ad (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object)))
 (if (= (getvar "tilemode") 0)
   (progn
     (if (= (getvar "cvport") 1)
       (progn
         (if (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "VIEWPORT"))))
           (progn
             (setq en (ssname ss 0)
                     ent (entget en)
                   vpno (dxf 69 ent)
             )
             (vla-Display (vlax-ename->vla-object en) :vlax-true)
             (vla-put-mspace ad :vlax-true)
             ; this to ensure trans later is working on correct viewport
             (setvar "cvport" vpno)
             (setq ok T)
           )
         )
       )
       (setq en (vlax-vla-object->ename (vla-get-activepviewport ad))
         ent (entget en)
             ok  T
       )
     )
     (if ok
       (progn
         (setq ven (vlax-ename->vla-object en))
         (if (/= 1 (logand 1 (dxf 90 ent))) ; detect perspective
           (if (= (vla-get-clipped ven) :vlax-false)
              (progn  ; not clipped
                  (vla-getboundingbox ven 'vpbl 'vpur)
                  (setq vpbl  (trans (vlax-safearray->list vpbl) 3 2)
                        msbl  (trans vpbl 2 1)
                        msbl  (trans msbl 1 0)
                        vpur  (trans (vlax-safearray->list vpur) 3 2)
                        msur  (trans vpur 2 1)
                        msur  (trans msur 1 0)
                        vpbr (list (car vpur) (cadr vpbl)0)
                        msbr  (trans vpbr 2 1)
                        msbr  (trans msbr 1 0)
                        vpul (list (car vpbl) (cadr vpur)0)
                        msul  (trans vpul 2 1)
                        msul  (trans msul 1 0)
                        plist (list (car msbl) (cadr msbl)
                                       (car msbr) (cadr msbr)
                                       (car msur) (cadr msur)
                                       (car msul) (cadr msul)
                                )
                   )
              )
              (progn  ; clipped
                (setq pl (entget (dxf 340 ent))
                      plist (vla-get-coordinates
                              (vlax-ename->vla-object (dxf -1 pl))
                            )
                      plist (vlax-safearray->list (vlax-variant-value plist))
                      n     0
                      pl    nil
                )
                (repeat (/ (length plist) 2)
                  (setq xy (trans (list (nth n plist) (nth (1+ n) plist)) 3 2)
                        xy  (trans xy 2 1)
                        xy  (trans xy 1 0)
                        pl (cons (car xy) pl)
                        pl (cons (cadr xy) pl)
                        n  (+ n 2)
                  )
                )
                (setq plist (reverse pl))
              )
           )
         )
         (setq width (dxf 40 ent)
                 height (dxf 41 ent)
         )
         (princ (strcat "Size: " (rtos width 2 2) " x " (rtos height 2 2) "\n"))
         (princ 
             (strcat 
                 "gdal_translate --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 600 --config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 4 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES "
                 "-outsize " (rtos (* width 10) 2 2) " 0 "
                 "-a_srs EPSG:9272 "
                 "-gcp 0 0 " (rtos (nth 6 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 7 plist) 2 2) " "
                 "-gcp " (rtos (* width 10) 2 2) " 0 " (rtos (nth 4 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 5 plist) 2 2) " "
                 "-gcp 0 " (rtos (* height 10) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 0 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 1 plist) 2 2) " "
                 "-mo CUTLINE=\"POLYGON((" (rtos (nth 0 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 1 plist) 2 2) "," (rtos (nth 2 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 3 plist) 2 2) "," (rtos (nth 4 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 5 plist) 2 2) "," (rtos (nth 6 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 7 plist) 2 2) "," (rtos (nth 0 plist) 2 2) " " (rtos (nth 1 plist) 2 2) "))\" "
                 "<file.pdf> <file.tif>"
             )
         )
       )
     )
   )
 )
 (if ss(vla-put-mspace ad :vlax-false)) ; equal (command "._pspace"))
 (princ)
)
```